# Decrease Logon Timeout Seaching for Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, domain

I've seen this same question asked on several other forums (and SE) with no definitive answer, so I'll try to explain as best I can so that anyone with info understands the problem:

**AD Server**

-Win2008 R2

-Not using roaming proviles

-Single small GPO

**Domain Client:** Win7Pro x64

-

**Problem:**
When a user is working from home (they take their laptop home), they need to wait about 45 seconds before being able to login. Once the mysterious "timeout" is reached, the local cached credentials are used and the system allows login.

**Root cause:**
The root cause is that the system is searching for domain controller, but the machine isn't on LAN/VPN so it can't access it since the user is working remote.

**Workaround:** 
If the user has Wifi disabled AND has unplugged network cable (machine has zero network) then it will login at normal speed. I assume this is because the client is not searching any network for the DC.

**My question:**
So what I need to know, is -- how can I shorten this "search time" so that the machine doesn't wait so long trying to find a DC that it will never find. Asking all my users to handle their wifi/network enable/disable just to log into the machine isn't going to work well. 
If the answer  is "that's impossible" then so be it, but I would like a definitive result on this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I dont know if possible, but when the DNS query fail Windows do a broadcast too to look for the domain name (you can do a wireshark to see the process). Disabling the nic prevent that process.

Comment: Yep, same findings here. I think it might not be possible to ditch the delay since it needs to do the broadcast and wait for a reply. Disabling NIC or having users ensure they're not connected to a network really isn't going to fly, so I think I may make some remote machines that aren't domain joined for the somewhat rare cases the staff needs to work remote.

Comment: You could join them in the domain, for the antivirus and such, but create them a local logon to use.